# What is the difference between "Resource" and "Method" for HTTP Header?

Tags: rest, http-headers, soapui

I´m trying to test some Rest Requests with SoapUI.
To make the HTTP Header, for each parameter option I had to set in :

- Name ( ex: "Content-Type" )
- Value ( ex: "application/json;charset=utf-8" )
- Style ( ex: "HEADER" )
- and... Level

For `Level`, I must choose between "Resource" or "Method".

What means "Header level" ?
What means "Resource" or "Method" for "Header level" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the [SoapUI documentation](https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html):

- Resource level parameters are added to all requests for this resource, regardless of method.
- Method level parameters are only added to requests with this specific method.

So if the parameter/header should be added for all methods, use resource level. If the parameters/header should be only added for a specific method, use method level.